# optional typed variadic arguments

Tags: php

PHP has [variadic argument unpacking](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking) since version 5.6.

```
function doSomething(User ...$users) {
     return count($users);
}
$userOrNoUserList = [$user1, null, $user2];
doSomething(...$userOrNoUserList); // wanted: 3
```

This throws the following error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to doSomething() must be an instance of user, null given

But I want to preserve the list structure inside `doSomething()`; I do not want to filter `null` values before invocation. Is it possible to allow `null` values too?

Comment: Did you try it? _Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to doSomething() must be an instance of user, null given_

Comment: @AbraCadaver yeah this is the problem I wonder if it is possible to define the function such that it does not raise an error

Comment: You should not pass null values in the first place. This sounds more like a design flaw.

Comment: can you explain why it is a design flaw to pass a list of optional values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define a [Nullable Type](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.nullable-types) using the `?` character before the type `User` (available in PHP 7.1.0):

```
function doSomething(?User ...$users) {
     return count($users);
}
```

Then you could call:

```
$userOrNoUserList = [$user1, null, $user3];
doSomething(...$userOrNoUserList); // 3
```

Comment: PHP >= 7.1.0 only.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, even though I hoped it is already available in PHP5.6, thank you!

Comment: Can you add a link to the manual for this please, I couldn't find one.

Comment: see also [What is a Nullable Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48450841/9193372)